# Security on Connecting to Salesforce from a Java app

Tags: community, integration, java, connected-apps

I was trying to connect to Salesforce and migrate data from mySQL database to Salesforce using Java. During the connection process I found that we have to give the **Username**, **Password** and **oAuth token** as parameters to the connection URL: **https://login.salesforce.com** but it seems there was no security in doing this way. 
Do we have any predefined security mechanism to connect to salesforce from external application say from a JAVA application?

Comment: By saying security what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Kiran Security in the sense i doesn't wanted my password or oAuth token to be tracked

Comment: If you already have an OAuth token, you don't need to log in... What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JWT Bearer Token profile - see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_using_a_JWT_Bearer_Token

You can register your app's signing certificate in your Salesforce org; your app then signs a JWT referencing a given user and POSTs it to `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`. If that user is authorized for the app, then the Salesforce authorization server will issue an access token for your app to access APIs on behalf of that user. The app never needs to know the user's password, and the org admin can revoke the app's access at any time by removing its signing cert from the org config.